# Issue with Communities login

Tags: community

We created site and incorporated site with standard visualforce pages for login and forgot password.

If we provide the forgot password page on the login screen there are two flows to login the user into the community:

A. User directly logged in site login page. => Here mobile developers are getting redirect url (sfdc://kkkkk) from salesforce. Based on redirect url they are redirecting user to mobile app.

B. User click forgot password link in login page it will redirect to forgot password page. In forgot password page user can click on cancel button it will redirect to login page. User can  provide valid credentials and click sign in button. => Here mobile developers are not getting redirect url (sfdc://kkkkk) from salesforce. That’s why they are not redirecting user to mobile app and the web view is redirected to the landing page, which is in our case the chatter page. We are not able to start the app properly and stuck in the web view until we restart the app.

Why are this things happen? We run out of ideas to solve this issues.

Comment: Can you provide your link for the site login? It is quite difficult to predict the behavior without analysing something.

Comment: Is anybody have Idea on this issue?